# do i need subdomain or domain/path for Admin panel?

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

Pardon me please. Am new to programming, so I don't know how it works.

I want know if I need subdomain like:

**www.admin-panel.myth.com** or **www.myth.com/path/subpath/admin-panel**

Please I need your help because am confused and don't have any idea how it is done.

Comment: Depends, both variants are okay, second is easier to make. First is more secure

Comment: Thanks for ur comment, it helpful to me. But which do you prefer btwn both?

Comment: Use second one with the path its totally fine for most cases.

Comment: Am thinking it will not be secure. Like someone can guess the path name. Or do you have any tips on how to make unguessable.